# Iterating over a custom type and access the property inside in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have custom type below:

```
-- (Int,Int,Int) = (Year, Month, Day)
type Birth = (Int, Int, Int)
type Book = String
data Author = Author Book Book Book Birth
```

I was thinking that **(Q1)** if there is a way to iterate over the property inside Author, which means a function 
`fun` applied to a `Author` type will return `Book` values separately. I have thought using

```
BookA :: Author -> Book
BookA (Author bkA _ _ _) = bkA
```

or `case...of`statement to get all three books separately, but it is too redundant. Is there a way iterately or recursively?

Also, **(Q2)** how can I get the BirthDay in a single function insdead of these:

```
birth :: Author -> Birth
birth (Author _ _ _ birth) = birth

bDay :: Birth -> Int
bDay (_,_,bDay) = bDay
```

Thank you guys so much.

Comment: Why not make it a list `Author [Book] Birth`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking that (**Q1**) if there is a way to iterate over the property inside `Author` (…)

Although you can do that with [**`Data`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html), it here looks a bit overkill. You can here simply match the tree books, and return these in a list:

```
BookA :: Author -> [Book]
BookA (Author bkA bkB bkC _) = [bkA, bkB, bkC]
```

Here it makes more sense however to define a *list* of `Book`s for an `Author`, since now you basically say that each `Author` has written *exactly* three books. By making a list, an `Author` can have written, zero, one, or more books:

```
data Author = Author [Book] Birth
```

You can even use records syntax, and let Haskell write the getters for you:

```
data Author = Author { booksA :: [Book], birth :: Birth }
```

> Also, (**Q2**) how can I get the BirthDay in a single function insdead of these  (…)

You can use nested patterns, like:

```
bday :: Author -> Birth
bdayA (Author _ _ _ (_, _, bd)) = bd
```

But often in Haskell one makes small *reusable* functions that can be combined. If you thus define `birth` and `bDay`, like you did, you can define the birthday of an `Author` with:

```
birth :: Author -> Birth
birth (Author _ _ _ birth) = birth

bDay :: Birth -> Int
bDay (_,_,bDay) = bDay

bDayA :: Author -> Int
bDayA = bDay . birth
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. The answer is really clear. I am also wondering if there is a way to do recursion in a single tupe with 3 elements, since I can only find questions about recursion on a list of tuples.

Comment: @GTTT: yes, by making use of the [`lens` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) for example. But it is a bit "overwhelming", with something like `toListOf each`.

Comment: That’s fine, I’ll check both documents. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Q1: You can get all three books at the same time by pattern matching, and then return them as a list:

```
books :: Author -> [Book]
books (Author a b c _) = [a, b, c]
```

But are you sure you want to define your `Author` like that? What if an author has two books or four? Such author wouldn't fit your definition, would it?

As @WillemVanOnsem pointed out in the comments, a more robust definition would be to make `Author` contain a list of `Book` instead of three books separately:

```
data Author = Author [Book] Birth
```

---

Q2: You can compose the two functions you have:

```
authorBDay :: Author -> Int
authorBDay = bDay . birth
```

Or, alternatively, you can pattern match directly:

```
authorBDay :: Author -> Int
authorBDay (Author _ _ _ (_,_,d)) = d
```

Patterns can be nested. That's their primary point.

Comment: But this (the nested pattern matching) does get pretty unwieldy as you add more levels of nesting, which is one of the main reasons [Lens](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/wiki/Overview) exists.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Basically authors have three book exactly saying in  the assignment. I was also wondering if there is a way to iterate over a single tuple with 3 elements?